# Wordpress second page displays the same content as my first

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I'm seeing my 2nd page displaying the exact same content as my first page.

I followed some articles online and added

```
<?php $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; ?>
<?php query_posts('showposts=16&paged=$paged'); ?>
```

just one line above my

```
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

But it's still the same... please help mee!!

edit: a link might have been helpful => http://nailian.ca/

Comment: change single quote to double quote or 'showposts=16&paged='.$paged

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here's your problem:

```
<?php query_posts('showposts=16&paged=$paged'); ?>
```

it should be:

```
<?php query_posts("showposts=16&paged=$paged"); ?>
```

Notice the different quote sign?
on single quote, dollar sign is treated as is, not parsed as variable [as stated in PHP doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single):

> Note: Unlike the double-quoted and heredoc syntaxes, variables and escape sequences for special characters will not be expanded when they occur in single quoted strings.

Comment: thank you sooooo much for your help! I actually did a ctrl+c/ctrl+v when I was implementing the above code, but woa there is NO WAY I could have realized the truth! Thank you again!!

Comment: And it should be `"&showposts` with ampersand right after opening quote. And while at it `showposts` is deprecated use `posts_per_page`.